# Error 109 when stopping Mongo DB running as a service (1.6.1)

Tags: service, mongodb

I'm running Mongo DB as windows service and every second time I stop the service it reports "Error 109: The pipe has been ended". Here is the command line being used to run the service

"C:\Temp\mongodb\bin\mongod" --service --serviceUser  --servicePassword  --dbpath C:\temp\db --rest --logpath C:\temp\db\log\mongo.log --logappend --directoryperdb

Comment: I've had this issue myself. Please vote on [SERVER-1434](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1434) in mongos bug database.

I've been contributing improvements to windows support in MongoDB. I will eventually get around to fixing this bug myself, but the more windows users that vote for windows bugs, the more attention 10gen pays to us.

Answer (score 1):

This bug was fixed for version 2.1.0 ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2833 ) and then resurfaced ( https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6771 ).  Hopefully it will be fixed again for version 2.2.0.

Comment: I saw this in version 2.6.2